# EAP-TLS : implementation and testing of a communication between two processes

Tags: tls, authentication, freeradius

I'm trying to make a simple **EAP-TLS** communication between two processes and capture it with Wireshark. Is there any library that can be used?  (like mbedtls  in the TLS case).

I have found a lot of TLS examples in c programming language, but nothing for **EAP-TLS**
If this couldn't be then, is it possible to use the same implementation provided in the source code of **freeradius** or **wpa_supplicant** and create **a simple c program**?

Comment: This looks like a pure coding question (off-topic here) but not one where you look for actual help with specific code of your own (usually off-topic on stackoverflow.com too). And it is also not clear for me why do you think that you can maybe not use the EAP-TLS implementation found in free software as the basis for implementing your own.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, 

""And it is also not clear for me why do you think that you can maybe not use the EAP-TLS implementation found in free software as the basis for implementing your own."" 
because i want to test the implementation found as opensource without install a server or something like this I need just a simple c program that shows how EAP-TLS works